# place input checkbox in same line of label

Tags: css, html, input

i am struggling to place input check-box in same line x-horizontal as in label. My check-box is placing in 2nd line. I have a div with background to image then label and then check-box. The margin between image and label div and margin between label and check need to be same. Many thanks in advance.

```
<div id="map_Marker_Check_Block">
 <div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school"><div class="marker_label">School</div> <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="school" type="checkbox"  /> </div> <br />
 <div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_gym"> <div class="marker_label">Gym</div> <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="gym" type="checkbox" /> </div><br />
</div>
```

### css

```
#map_Marker_Check_Block {
background-color:yellow;
display:block;
position:absolute;
width:20em;
height:400px;
top:0;
right:0;
z-index:10;
overflow-y:auto;
}

.marker_label {
margin-left:50px;
line-height:48px;
width:130px;
background-color:green;
}

.marker_ckeckbox {   
float:right; 
}

.markerDiv {
width:19em;
height:48px;
margin-left:5px;
}

#maker_school {  background: url("img1.png") no-repeat; }

#maker_gym{   background: url("img2.png") no-repeat;   }
```

Comment: You should use a `<label>` as your label instead of a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school"><label class="marker_label">School</label> <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="school" type="checkbox"  /> </div> <br />
<div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_gym"> <label class="marker_label">Gym</label> <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="gym" type="checkbox" /> </div><br />
```

### css

```
.marker_ckeckbox {   
 float:right; 
 position: relative;
 top: -35px;
}

.marker_label {    
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use TOP and POSITION styles for checkbox:

```
.marker_ckeckbox {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
}
```

But, I think the elements must be structured in a different way.

Or as Musa said use label instead of div:

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/qaprB/1/

Comment: i have use label with css property display:block with position: relative and top -35px and it works ... many thanks .

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/XUErp/

```
.marker_label {
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
    line-height:48px;
    width:130px;
    background-color:green;
}
.marker_ckeckbox {
    margin-top:15px;
    float:right;
}
```